# Polyakov loops and Wilson loops as order parameters

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, lattice-gauge-theory

At zero temperature, the confinement/deconfinement criterion is the area/length law of the following non-local parameter called the Wilson loop: 
\begin{eqnarray}
W=\text{Tr}\exp\left(\oint_CA_idx^i\right), 
\end{eqnarray}
where the path ordering is implicitly imposed on the Euclidean spacetime.

On the other hand, at a finite temperature of $\beta^{-1}=k_\text{B}T$, the Polyakov loop is used as the order parameter for confinement/deconfinement: 
\begin{eqnarray}
P&\equiv&\text{Tr}\exp\left(\oint_{S_\tau^1}A_idx^i\right)\nonumber\\
&=&\text{Tr}\exp\left(\oint_{S_\tau^1}A_\tau d\tau\right), 
\end{eqnarray}
where $S^1_\tau=[0,\beta)$ and we have a periodic condition: $A_i(\tau=0)=A_i(\tau=\beta)$.

My questions are

1. why we cannot use Wilson loop as the criterion at a finite temperature, e.g. can we use a Wilson loop staying at a time slice, namely $C$ above taken space-like within a fixed time slice?
2. why the Polyakov loop cannot be the order parameter at zero temperature, e.g. can we simply take the zero-temperature limit $\beta\rightarrow+\infty$ in $P$ above? I guess that it may not be a well-defined limit generally, but I cannot be quantitatively sure.